# Generating boolean dataframe based on contents in series and dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, boolean, series

I have:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            [22, 33, 44],
            [55, 11, 22],
            [33, 55, 11],
        ],
        index=["abc", "def", "ghi"],
        columns=list("abc")
    ) # size(3,3)
```

and:

```
unique = pd.Series([11, 22, 33, 44, 55]) # size(1,5)
```

then I create a new df based on `unique` and `df`, so that:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(index=unique, columns=df.columns) # size(5,3)
```

From this newly created df, I'd like to create a new boolean df based on `unique` and `df`, so that the end result is:

```
 df_new = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            [0, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 0],
        ],
        index=unique,
        columns=df.columns
    )
```

This new df is either true or false depending on whether the value is present in the original dataframe or not. For example, the first column has three values: [22, 55, 33]. In a df with dimensions (5,3), this first column would be: [0, 1, 1, 0, 1] i.e. [0, 22, 33, 0 , 55]

I tried `filter2 = unique.isin(df)` but this doesn't work, also notnull. I tried applying a filter but the dimensions returned were incorrect. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then check if not missing values by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html), cast to integers for `True->1` and `False->0` mapping and last remove index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df_new = (df.stack()
            .reset_index(name='v')
            .pivot('v','level_1','level_0')
            .notna()
            .astype(int)
            .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df_new)
    a  b  c
11  0  1  1
22  1  0  1
33  1  1  0
44  0  0  1
55  1  1  0
```

Helper Series is not necessary, but if there is more values or is necessary change order by helper Series use add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
#added 66
unique = pd.Series([11, 22, 33, 44, 55,66])

df_new = (df.stack()
            .reset_index(name='v')
            .pivot('v','level_1','level_0')
            .reindex(unique)
            .notna()
            .astype(int)
            .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))
print (df_new)
    a  b  c
11  0  1  1
22  1  0  1
33  1  1  0
44  0  0  1
55  1  1  0
66  0  0  0
```

Comment: great, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!